# Find the least divergent points between a Git repo and a CVS repo

Tags: git, cvs

I'm trying to bring a CVS and Git repo back into line (so I can get about merging the improvements from Git, mostly).

Is there a way to ask Git, 
"Find me the closest (or identical) commit to match the files in this CVS checkout?"

I don't mind if I have to do this separately for each file.

(The two repos appear to have a common parent, but may have no exact match. Dates etc are all over the place. It's a mess!)

Comment: Also, to the mod-types out there, am I justified in voting to close this as duplicate? The circumstances may not be exactly the same, and it can be hard to have a good dialogue on an old question, but I certainly don't want to repost my answer from there on this one!

Comment: Thanks Jefromi, I think you're right. How do I vote to close this as a dupe too? :)

Comment: I found it. (Is there a reason I shouldn't just delete it?)

Comment: Don't delete it. Duplicate questions are a valuable way to help people search. (Jeff Atwood says something like "people have an uncanny ability to ask identical questions with zero words in common.) It took me a while to find that previous question, and someone who's lazy about searching, or just not as familiar with the site, would probably never find it. This increases the odds.